# Bokeh: DateRangeSlider decreases the year by 1 when the chosen start date is Jan 1st

Tags: python, bokeh

While I was trying out DateRangeSlider for another question here on SO, I found out that the start date 01/01/2017 was getting changed to 01/01/2016 on the slider. When I slid the date to Jan 2nd, it displayed the year correctly. It seems like a bug. If not, how do I fix it?

[image: DateRangeSlider example]

Below is the code that I used:

```
from datetime import date

from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout

from bokeh.io import curdoc

date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", start=date(2017, 1, 1), end=date.today(), value=(date(2017, 9, 7), date(2017, 10, 15)), step=1)

l = layout(children=[[date_range_slider]], sizing_mode='fixed')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "DateRangeSlider Example"
```

Comment: Raise this issue in the bokeh community ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem in previous versions, but has since been fixed. Bokeh 0.12.10, e.g., displays your code as expected:

[image]

So the answer is to upgrade to a newer version with the fix.